# Dialogo personalizados

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Tengo una duda, como hago yo en el momento de que ingreso un texto en un EditText de una actividad principal, me aparezca luego en un **dialogo** personalizado como titulo?

Comment: Fijate la clase DialogFragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un AlertDialog para mostrar el dialogo con el título que quieras de la siguiente manera:

```
//this es el contexto de tu Activity
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("AQUI EL TÍTULO QUE QUIERAS");
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("AQUÍ EL MENSAJE");
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", null);
alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

Puedes obtener más información en la documentación de Android, acerca de los Cuadros de diálogo en este enlace: [Cuadros de diálogo | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=es-419)